# Phone not getting listed in devices window in eclipse upon usb connection

Tags: android, eclipse, usb-debugging

I have Asus Zenfone2 and I want to do usb debugging for android on my phone. I have done the following:

1. enabled USB debugging from developer options.
2. Downloaded OEM driver for Zenfone 2 from [here](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=ASUS%20ZenFone%202%20(ZE551ML)&p=39&s=1). Unzipped the downloaded file. It had the following files:
   [image: OEM Driver]
3. From the Device manager selected Portable Devices > ASUS_Z00AD > Right click and Update Driver Software > Browse my computer for driver software > Selected C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Downloads\ASUS_Android_USB_drivers_for_Windows_20150212\Windows_XP_VISTA_7_8_8.1 > Next.
4. I got the message :

[image: Result]

But My device is still not listed in the devices window in eclipse.

Comment: One mad question. Did you try with different usb cable?

Comment: what usb connection option you have selected while connecting your device to computer? e.g media device/mass storage/camera device?

Comment: i have a feeling this question will get deleted as it's not a real programming question, but before that happens, try this: https://software.intel.com/system/files/managed/28/0c/IntelAndroidDrvSetup1.9.0.zip

Comment: @Y.S my device is connected as Media Device(MTP)

Comment: @user3694532 I have many time cry with cable. It shows different kinds error. Once i change cable it will work. In your case i am not sure but try once.

Comment: @josephus this link says Access Denied

Comment: @Amsheer, I tried using a different cable. still no luck.

Comment: @user3694532 try this one: https://software.intel.com/protected-download/385047/494732

Comment: @josephus i installed this, but still its not getting listed.

Comment: Hey Guys I got the solution.. I was updating driver for the device listed under portable devices. But when I updated it for the ones listed under other devices.. It worked.

Comment: Really appreciate you all for your quick responses :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was updating driver software for device listed under Portable Devices in Device manager. I did the update for the ones listed under other devices (Android was listed under it), and the device started showing in the list.